# removing garbage characters from txt

Tags: python, string

I'm parsing webpages on Edgar.

I found that the text files on Edgar(especially recent ones labelled as Interactive data) contain characters which seem to have no meaning (at least to me)

The followings are example of those characters.

```
M="`J+SPO2!O9B!3:6=N:69I8V%N="!!8V-O=6YT:6YG(%!O;&EC
M:65S("A$971A:6QS(#2`S,2P@,C`Q,SQB
```

Since, they took a lot of memories from my computer I want to remove them.

My questions are,

1. Do those characters really have no meaning? (If they do I really want to remove them)
2. I thought I could delete them by using regexpression,

   data = re.sub('([A-Z][0-9]\{}[]/?,.;:|)*~`!^-_+<>@#$%^\\=(\'\"){30, 99999999999999999999999999999999999}', "", data)

(data is a string which contains those characters)

However, I have failed to remove them. Could you give me some help?

Comment: I bet they are not txt files

Comment: How did you test that regular expression? Try http://regex101.com